# Basic question about defining a character.

Tags: abstract-algebra, linear-transformations, group-homomorphism, characters

I am reading Character Theory of Finite Groups, by Martin Isaacs. If $G$ is a fixed finite group, and $M_i$ is an irreducible $\mathbb{C}[G]$-module, then the book defines $\mathfrak{X}_i$ by choosing a basis for $M_i$ and letting $\mathfrak{X}_i$ be the resolting representation of $\mathbb{C}[G]$. My question is, how dose choosing a basis for $M_i$, result in a representation of $\mathbb{C}[G]$? I know a representation of $\mathbb{C}[G]$, is a homomorphism from $\mathbb{C}[G]$ into Aut($\mathbb{C}$).

Comment: Your question is confusing. A $\Bbb{C}[G]$-module is the same as an homomorphism $G\to GL(V)$ for some complex vector space $V$, aka. a complex representation of $G$. The trace (=the character) of that representation (assuming $V$ is finite dimensional which doesn't loose generality when $G$ is a finite group) is obtained by choosing any basis of $V$ so the homomorphism becomes $\rho:G\to GL_d(\Bbb{C})$ where $d=\dim(V)$ and letting $\chi(g)=tr(\rho(g))$.

Comment: A representation of $\Bbb C[G]$ is an algebra homomorphism $\Bbb C[G]\to{\rm End}(V)$ for a vector space $V$. (Nobody would say "${\rm Aut}\Bbb C$," which is false and misleading.) As reuns points out, this is equivalent to a group homomorphism $G\to GL(V)$ (which is continuous/smooth if applicable usually). The basis for $M_i$ does not "result in a representation of $\Bbb C[G]$" unless you artificially define a representatiosn with matrices. But either way, the basis does provide you with a way to represent group elements as matrices.